# How to list files with metadata on one line in HDFS with bash?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I am writing a bash script that scans HDFS and do stuff with the output.

Fetching file names is easy with the following:

```
    for line in $(hdfs dfs -ls -t -r -C -R $HDFS_CLEANING_STG); do
        echo $line
    done
```

Output:

```
/dir
/dir/file1
/dir/file2
```

However, it removes the file size, date, rights, etc.

With the same method but without the `-C` flag, it gives the metadata but not on one line only:

Output example:

```
-rw-rw-r--+
3
hdfs
hdfs
34448169
2020-05-04
11:36
/dir/file
```

I would like to get these information, but with this output (like a "normal" `ls`):

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 3 hdfs hdfs 34448169 2020-05-04 11:36 /dir/file
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: What do you do in the for loop? How do you print?

Comment: @FrancescoLucianò I'm just "echoing" the $line variable. Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the for loop. When you do `for line in $(hdfs dfs -ls -t -r -C -R $HDFS_CLEANING_STG);` , it iterates over each word, not over each line. So, every time it faces a white space, the value of `line` changes with the word you just read.

A simple way to fix it is doing like this:

```
for line in "$(hdfs dfs -ls -t -r -C -R $HDFS_CLEANING_STG)"; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Or like this:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -t -r -C -R $HDFS_CLEANING_STG | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: That's it ! But without the -C flag.

Comment: @Francesco Lucianò, +1, because of good catch about [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/).